# Node.js GraphicsMagick append an image without saving the file

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphicsmagick

I am looking to append and image to another which is simple. But what I need to do is create an image with gm, and place at the bottom of another *without* saving the first image on the server. It's easy If I can save my images first, but so as things go, that's not the case.

Create the image

```
gm(600, 100, '#000')
.fill('rgba(0,0,0,0.7)')
.fill('#fff')
.font("Arial.ttf", 16)
.drawText(15, 30, 'Heading here')
.drawText(15, 55, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet")
.write('text.jpg', function (err) {
  if (err){
    console.log(err)
  } else {
    console.log('done');  
  } 
});
```

Resize another and append the first image:

```
gm('img.jpg')
.resize(600)
.append('bottom.jpg')
.write('finished.jpg', function (err) {
  if (err){
    console.log(err)
  } else {
    console.log('done');    
  } 
});
```

Is there a way I can do this without writing the first file?

Comment: GM has streams, so you can stream the first to the second, or you could even use `.toBuffer()` to get a buffer instead of saving it.

Comment: Seems `append()` should accept a GM object as well, so you can do this -> https://jsfiddle.net/avasr4j9/

Comment: Thanks @adeneo. I actually tried that approach earlier and it wasn't working for me. Have you tested that locally?

Comment: Nope, can't really test it right now.